# Fake-rivalry stimulus

Tags: psychopy

for a binocular rivalry experiment using color blobs (created with GratingStim using a gaussian mask), I need to draw a fake rivalry stimulus. That is, I need a round color blob that has one color for example on the top (25% of the color blob) and another color below (75% of the color blob). Additionally, I would like the twocolored fake rivalry blob to have a gaussian mask as my real rivalry stimuli do. Also it would be good to have a fuzzy color transition in the fake rivalry stimulus. I hope it's clear what I mean.

One solution I thought of was to draw two rectangles with blurred edges and then lay a gaussian alpha mask over them. In order to get the color proportions right, I would only have to move the two rectangles behind the mask. Is there a way to put a alpha-maks over an entire window?

Another solution would be to use ShapeStim as is suggested in this post explaining how to draw a semi circle : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/psychopy-users/L9TYIrf9eJk/m0zIj0N23bMJ  I would have to play around with the vertices, but I think it should work. The only thing that worries me here is that ShapeStim has no mask attribute to blur the edges.

Can you think of a way to do it? 
Thank you very much!

Lilla

System specifications: 
Psychopy v1.83.01  running on iOS 10.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second update, even nicer result:

```
# Set up stimuli
from psychopy import visual, event
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

win = visual.Window([500,500])
win2 = visual.Window([500,500])

#magic numpy stuff /scipy stuff, adapted from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html
mean1 = [0, 0]
 #the smaller the value, the bigger the visible blob
cov1 = [[0.03, 0], [0, 0.09]]  #in this mask, it should be 50/50

cov2 = [[0.05,0],[0,0.4]]       #in this mask, the color with this mask is the smaller one

m1, m2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, 2000).T# * np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, 5000).T 
for i in xrange(len(m2)):
    if m2[i] >= 0:
       m2[i] = m2[i]* 0.5#np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2,1).T[0]

values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = gaussian_kde(values)

xmin = m1.min()
xmax = m1.max()
ymin = m2.min()
ymax = m2.max()

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:128j, ymin:ymax:128j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([m1, m2])
kernel = gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)    #this array will be the mask
Z = Z - 1
for i in xrange(128):
    for j in xrange(128):       #it will neverbe smaller than -1
        if Z[i][j] > 1: 
            Z[i][j] = 1


# Draw them on top of each other 

perc75 = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, size=250, color='green',pos=(0.0, 0.0), mask =Z)
perc25 = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, size=250, color='red',pos=(0.0, 0.0), mask = 'raisedCos', maskParams={'fringeWidth':0.8}) 

perc25.setAutoDraw(True)
perc75.setAutoDraw(True)
win.flip()
event.waitKeys()
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? You can then locate the blobs where you want, e.g. for one eye. No need to do whole-window stuff.

```py
# Set up stimuli
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window([500,500])
blob_large = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, mask='gauss', size=1, color='red')
blob_small = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, mask='gauss', size=0.5, color='green', maskParams={'sd':6})

# Draw them on top of each other
blob_large.draw()
blob_small.draw()
win.flip()

# Wait for keyboard before quitting.
event.waitKeys()
```

Comment: Dear Jonas, thank you for your idea, I think i will go for that if I can't get it to work with pygame. From your suggestion, I figured that I didn't describe well, what I had in mind: Rather than two blobs above each other, I would prefer a blob with the upper 25% or so percent being green and the lower rest being red, like in Pearson, Clifford and Tong 2008 (supplemental data): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982208007239. Do you happen to have any ideas for this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Dear Jonas, I have another idea: I could plot the two stimuli with a custom made mask (that is an array) above them. Is it true then, that the mask would have to have the dimensions of the stimulus in question? Thank you for your help! lilla

Answer (score 0):

Update on my question: the following exemplar code solves the problem:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# adapted from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/psychopy-users/69p-aAWiDGI/e4iT43cHDeEJ
from psychopy import visual, event

win = visual.Window([500,500])

#stimuli
perc25 = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, size=1, color='RED',pos=(0.0, 0.0), mask = 'raisedCos', maskParams={'fringeWidth':0.8}) 
perc75 = visual.GratingStim(win, sf=0, size=0.8, color='green',pos=(0.0, -0.15), mask = 'raisedCos', maskParams={'fringeWidth':0.6}) 

#prepare for the screenshot
Stimlist = [perc25, perc75]
delta = .5# larger is bigger, slower
dx = delta * win.size[1]/win.size[0]
dy = delta
rect = (-dx, +dy, +dx, -dy)#size of the screenshot
screenshot = visual.BufferImageStim(win, stim=Stimlist,rect = rect, mask = 'gauss', pos=(0.0, 0.0)) # mask can also be 'raisedCos' with a smaller delta, for exmple .2
screenshot.draw()

win.flip()
event.waitKeys()
```